# Saving+reading sorted maps to a file in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm saving a nested map of data to disk via `spit`. I want some of the maps inside my map to be sorted, and to stay sorted when I `slurp` the map back into my program. Sorted maps don't have a unique literal representation, so when I `spit` the map-of-maps onto disk, the sorted maps and the unsorted maps are represented the same, and `#(read-string (slurp %))`ing the data makes every map the usual unsorted type. Here's a toy example illustrating the problem:

```
(def sorted-thing (sorted-map :c 3 :e 5 :a 1))
;= #'user/sorted-thing
(spit "disk" sorted-thing)
;= nil
(def read-thing (read-string (slurp "disk")))
;= #'user/read-thing

(assoc sorted-thing :b 2)
;= {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :e 5}
(assoc read-thing :b 2)
;= {:b 2, :a 1, :c 3, :e 5}
```

Is there some way to read the maps in as sorted in the first place, rather than converting them to sorted maps after reading? Or is this a sign that I should be using some kind of real database?

Comment: Look into [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) with tagged elements.

Comment: if you write it out as JSON, and read it back into a `sorted-map`, does that satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @Kevin how does one tell `clojure.data.json` what to read an object in as? Or did you mean a different library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*print-dup*` dynamically rebindable Var is meant to support this use case:

```
(binding [*print-dup* true]
  (prn (sorted-map :foo 1)))
; #=(clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create {:foo 1})
```

The commented out line is what gets printed.

It so happens that it also affects `str` when applied to Clojure data structures, and therefore also `spit`, so if you do

```
 (binding [*print-dup* true]
   (spit "foo.txt" (sorted-map :foo 1)))
```

the map representation written to `foo.txt` will be the one displayed above.

Admittedly, I'm not 100% sure whether this is documented somewhere; if you feel uneasy about this, you could always `spit` the result of using `pr-str` with `*print-dup*` bound to `true`:

```
(binding [*print-dup* true]
  (pr-str (sorted-map :foo 1)))
;= "#=(clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create {:foo 1})"
```

(This time the last line is the value returned rather than printed output.)

Clearly you'll have to have `*read-eval*` bound to `true` to be able to read back these literals. That's fine though, it's exactly the purpose it's meant to serve (reading code from trusted sources).

Comment: You never cease to amaze me. Great answer.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, but it's not perfect: this always uses the default map comparator, so if you have a sorted map that's sorted by something else, the one you read back in won't match. There's not a lot you can do about this, short of writing a custom serializer that writes something like `#sorted/map [(fn [...]) {:foo 1}]`, and a corresponding data reader.  And of course, then you have to make sure the comparator function can be serialized too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its necessarily a sign that you should be using a database, but I do think its a sign that you shouldn't be using `spit`.  When you write your sorted maps to disk, don't use the map literal syntax.  If you write it out in the following format, read-string will work:

```
(def sorted-thing (eval (read-string "(sorted-map :c 3 :e 5 :a 1)")))
(assoc sorted-thing :b 2)
;= {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :e 5}
```

Comment: This does what I was asking, and I will note it for the future. Pulling all of the entries (potentially thousands) out of each sorted map (potentially hundreds) to place them in a call to `sorted-map` each time I want to save sounds like it could get slow, though. I should really look around for some kind of database...

Comment: @James, what do you think `clojure.core/pr-str` is doing now? It's pulling all the entries out of each map to place them inside of `\{ \}` characters. The cost of doing this yourself instead won't bankrupt you.

Comment: No more than doing it via `pr-str` would have, you're right. Thank you for pointing that out.